# How can ı use st.columns with st.tabs (Streamlit)

Tags: python, streamlit

I want to work tabs and columns together in streamlit

This is what ım trying to do

```
with st.tabs("tab1"):
    with st.columns("col1"):
        st.selectbox("City", ["City1", "City2"-])
    with st.columns("col2"):
        st.selectbox("District", ["District1", "District2"])

with st.tabs("tabs2"):
    with st.columns("another_col1"):
         st.selectbox("Another City", ["Another_City1", "Another_City2"])
    with st.columns("another_col2"):
         st.selectbox("Another District", ["Another_District1", "Another_District2"])
```

**When I open each tab separately, I want to see different selectboxes in each. How can I do that ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to initialize `st.columns()` in every tab.

```py
tab1, tab2 = st.tabs(["tab1", "tab2"])

with tab1:
    col1, col2 = st.columns(2)
    with col1:
        st.selectbox("City", ["City1", "City2"])
    with col2:
        st.selectbox("District", ["District1", "District2"])

with tab2:
    col1, col2 = st.columns(2)
    with col1:
        st.selectbox("Another City", ["Another_City1", "Another_City2"])
    with col2:
        st.selectbox("Another District", ["Another_District1", "Another_District2"])
```

Comment: i didn't mean that.If I use it as in the code above, for example, the selectboxes in tab one appear on all tabs.But I want it to appear on whichever tab I wrote it for.

Comment: You mean when you click tab1 you want only the two selectboxes, and same with tab2?

Comment: I edited the answer, what I seem to understand is that you want each tab to show only it's individual selectboxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
tab1, tab2 = st.tabs(["tab1", "tab2"])

with tab1:
    col1, col2 = st.columns(2)
    with col1:
        st.selectbox("City", ["City1", "City2"])
    with col2:
        st.selectbox("District", ["District1", "District2"])

with tab2:
    col1, col2 = st.columns(2)
    with col1:
        st.selectbox("Another City", ["Another_City1", "Another_City2"])
    with col2:
        st.selectbox("Another District", ["Another_District1", "Another_District2"])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).